# Who shared my Facebook post?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using any Facebook API for Python, I am trying to get the # of people who shared my post and who those people are. I currently have the first part..

```
>>> from facepy import *
>>> graph = GraphAPI("CAAEr")
>>> g = graph.get('apple/posts?limit=20')
>>> g['data'][10]['shares']
```

That gets the count, but I want to know who those people are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sharedposts` connection will give you more information about the shares of a post. You have to `GET` `USER_ID?fields=sharedposts`.  This information doesn't appear in the doc.

This follows your code:

```
# Going through each of your posts one by one
for post in g['data']:

    # Getting post ID
    id = post['id']   # Gives USERID_POSTID
    id[-17:]          # We know that a post ID is represented by 17 numerals

    # Another Graph request to get the shared posts
    shares = graph.get(id + '?fields=sharedposts')  

    print('Post' id, 'was shared by:')

    # Displays the name of each sharer
    print share['from']['name'] for share in shares['data']
```

It is my first time with Python, there might be some syntax errors in the code. But you got the idea.

Comment: Bruckwert

Thanks, you are on the right track. after a little bit of manipulation, I got it. Thanks again