# Viewing Shares information for a Facebook post using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to use the Facebook graph api on rails to find for a specific post who shared it. Looking through the documentation and the api data it doesn't seem that this information is available for a specific post. I am able to get the likes and comments information, however not the shares.

Would anyone know whether the current Facebook Api gives that information? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Graph API, do a request to `graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=sharedposts`.
Iterate through the resulting array to get the sharers' identity.

Example in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17501595/1515819).

Comment: Thanks, but I think there's a problem with the FacebookGraph gem on Rails. I tried your solution on the API level and it works, however on the Gem level it doesn't seem that this field exists. Thanks again.